# Issue Saving Certificate to iOS Keychain -25300 (not found) if deleting, but -25299 (duplicate item) if adding

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I've hit an interesting issue with the Apple keychain and am wondering what I am doing wrong.

```
    func saveCert(accessGroup: String? = nil, certData: Data, label: String? = nil) -> Error? {
        var query = createKeychainAddQueryDict()
        if let accessGroup = accessGroup {
            query[String(kSecAttrAccessGroup)] = accessGroup
        }

        query[String(kSecValueData)] = certData
        query[String(kSecClass)] = kSecClassCertificate

        if let label = label {
            query[String(kSecAttrLabel)] = label
        }

        var status = SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)
        if status != noErr {
            print("Error deleting cer from keychain. Error: \(status)")
        }

        let resultCode = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
        return getErrorFromKeychainCode(code: resultCode)
    }
```

I'm saving a self signed certificate, but I've verified the serial number is different for each item I'm trying to store.

I get a -25300 error (cannot find item) when I try to delete the cert out, but I get a -25299 error (duplicate item already exists) when I try to save into the keychain.

I'm stumped as to why or how, loading or deleting the key out of that location are both failing, and saving is declaring the position is taken.

Any insight? I've experimented with hardcoding a number of random labels that I've never used before, and they too get the duplicate entry error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried lots of things, and none of them worked. I eventually found out that the `kSecCertificate` class uses the issuer and serial number attributes to compute its uniqueId.

Because I'm using a self-signed certificate the `SecCertificateCreateWithData` operation fails with result nil. I believe this is causing all my certificates to evaluate to the same empty - empty id. I tried storing this same data in a kSecGenericPassword, and set a distinct account attribute, and the issue has gone away.

Answer (score 2):

I found two solutions:

1. Request values for a particular key later. Use async delayed. From time to time the Keychain doesn't provide the result with -25300. The keychain is an SQLite database too. It seems the database is currently busy. So, request the data later.
2. You have already written something into this key but, you used another protection level. To avoid this, use keys with protection level inside its name. E.g., `someKey` into `someKey-afterFirstUnlock`